# Using Tesseract for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, tesseract

Im using tesseract OCR and it only reads 300 dpi images, when i take photos using UIImage picker controller camera the images are in 72 dpi how can i take images in 300 dpi like the stock app in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Tesseract on an iPad with iOS7 and the following code successfully presents the UIImagePickerController and I get an image back that I can readily OCR with Tesseract:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    iosPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    iosPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    iosPicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
    iosPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    iosPicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    iosPicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    iosPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    iosPicker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:iosPicker animated:YES completion:^{}];

}
```

Side note: iosPicker is an instance variable defined in the interface for the view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i found the problem, it was the cropping method when i use CGRectMake it won't read